# Remove objects that meet a condition and their children also meet the condition - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have this type of object:

```
[
{
    "fieldID": 10,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Cliente",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 1,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código cliente",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        },
        {
            "fieldID": 2,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": true
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "fieldID": 20,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Aseguradora",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 3,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código",
            "items": [
                {
                    "fieldID": 4,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Id",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "fieldID": 5,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fieldID": 7,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical2",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "__deleteConditions": false
                },
                {
                    "fieldID": 6,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
                    "items": [],
                    "__deleteConditions": true
                }
            ],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        }
        
    ]
}
```

]

And I want to go through all the array of objects (children included) and delete all those objects that have the property: "__deleteConditions": true

That is to say, I want to return an array with all the objects whose "__deleteConditions" is false.

I need help, as I have not been able to solve this problem recursively.
Thank you very much for your help. <3

Comment: [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) should do the trick. Just call it recursively on the `item` array.

Comment: How? I have tried to do it but I can't get it to return the clean array as I want it to.

Comment: Try to do it for the original array. If that works, try to rewrite it to do it recursively. If you have trouble with the recursive path, show your attempts and we may be able to help out.

Comment: The thing about recursion is that you really just have to kind of bang your head against the wall for a while but eventually it starts to click.

Comment: I tried this: function test(object){
  return object.filter(x => {
    if(x.isGroup){
        return test(x.items)
    }else{
    return !x.__deleteConditions
    } 
});
}

 console.log(JSON.stringify(test(object)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems useful to build this atop a generic function which will filter your `item`-children objects according to an arbitrary predicate, and then write your version by passing that a function which checks the `__deleteCondition`.

We can do it like this:

```js
const deepFilter = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .filter (fn) 
     .map (({items = [], ...rest}) => ({...rest, items: deepFilter (fn) (items)}))

const removeDeleteCondition = deepFilter ((x) => ! x .__deleteConditions) 

const input = [{fieldID: 10, isGroup: true, itemDisplayName: "Cliente", items: [{fieldID: 1, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Código cliente", items: [], __deleteConditions: false}, {fieldID: 2, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Apellidos", items: [], __deleteConditions: true}]}, {fieldID: 20, isGroup: true, itemDisplayName: "Aseguradora", items: [{fieldID: 3, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Código", items: [{fieldID: 4, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Id", items: [{fieldID: 5, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Numerical", items: [], __deleteConditions: true}, {fieldID: 7, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Numerical2", items: [], __deleteConditions: false}], __deleteConditions: false}, {fieldID: 6, isGroup: false, itemDisplayName: "Apellidos", items: [], __deleteConditions: true}], __deleteConditions: false}]}]

console .log (removeDeleteCondition (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

`deepFilter` is our generic, reusable function, able to use on other parts of our system or other systems we might create.  `removeDeleteCondition` is created by the simple technique of passing a predicate function to `deepFilter`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using combination array filter and map. Please find the below.

Hope this helps

```js
const data = [
{
    "fieldID": 10,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Cliente",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 1,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código cliente",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        },
        {
            "fieldID": 2,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": true
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "fieldID": 20,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Aseguradora",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 3,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código",
            "items": [
                {
                    "fieldID": 4,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Id",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "fieldID": 5,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fieldID": 7,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical2",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "__deleteConditions": false
                },
                {
                    "fieldID": 6,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
                    "items": [],
                    "__deleteConditions": true
                }
            ],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        }
        
    ]
}]


  
  const arrayToTree = (arr) =>
  arr.filter(item => !item.__deleteConditions)
    .map(child => ({ ...child, items: child.items?.length ? arrayToTree(child.items) : []  }));
  
 

console.log('result', arrayToTree(data));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you simply need to remove all items with delete condition and then recurse on the remaining items

```js
const data = [
{
    "fieldID": 10,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Cliente",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 1,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código cliente",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        },
        {
            "fieldID": 2,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
            "items": [],
            "__deleteConditions": true
        }
    ]
}, 
{
    "fieldID": 20,
    "isGroup": true,
    "itemDisplayName": "Aseguradora",
    "items": [
        {
            "fieldID": 3,
            "isGroup": false,
            "itemDisplayName": "Código",
            "items": [
                {
                    "fieldID": 4,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Id",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "fieldID": 5,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": true
                        },
                        {
                            "fieldID": 7,
                            "isGroup": false,
                            "itemDisplayName": "Numerical2",
                            "items": [],
                            "__deleteConditions": false
                        }
                    ],
                    "__deleteConditions": false
                },
                {
                    "fieldID": 6,
                    "isGroup": false,
                    "itemDisplayName": "Apellidos",
                    "items": [],
                    "__deleteConditions": true
                }
            ],
            "__deleteConditions": false
        }
        
    ]
}]

const clearEntry = (entry) => {
  entry.items = entry.items.filter(item => !item.__deleteConditions)
  entry.items.forEach(clearEntry)
}

data.forEach(clearEntry)
console.log(data)
```